# Using uuid[] type in Postgres with kotlin and hibernate

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, kotlin

I'm pretty new to Kotlin and whole JVM world and I'm trying to figure out how should I use that type. I was trying to implement it as mentioned in this tutorial: https://medium.com/@sajithvijesekar/spring-jpa-data-with-postgres-array-types-a6cc4be421e2 but as a result I received: `No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 2003` during app startup. I wanted to use that field in entity this way:

```
@Entity
class Model(@field:Id val id: UUID, var name: String) {
  @Column
  @Type(type = "com.dal.type.GenericArrayUserType")
  private val tagsProjection = arrayOf<UUID>()
}
```

Is that error related with way how I use it in my model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I know what I was doing wrong. I haven't included `@Column(columnDefinition = "uuid[]")` in my Entity